# How to expose AWS Fargate ECS containers to internet with Route53 DNS?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I have an ECS Task running on fargate and my service get an public ip address automatically. How do I simply expose fargate task to internet with Route53 dns? I was looking around the internet for a whole day today an I couldn't find an example about this simplest possible scenario where I just want to expose a port from said task to the internet and map a Route53 record to point to its ip address.

If I understood correctly from the minimal information I found is that I would have to create an vpc endpoint but I couldn't find information about how to route the traffic to a task/container.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this problem. I was able to route traffic to a single container service in public subnets via application load balancers. However, now, I cannot reproduce this. Did you try the ALB yet?

Comment: No I didn't, do I really have to create a load balancer for such simple use case?

Comment: I figured out my problem. I had my ALB set to internal instead of internet facing. This article may help. https://appfleet.com/blog/automate-docker-container-deployment-to-aws-ecs-using-cloudformation/